# In Scala, how to instantiate a class N times in another class

Tags: scala

I have a class **A**, that i wanted to instantiate N times in another class, **B** where N is a parameter to the class **B**. Is there a way to do this using any looping methods?

```
class A {
   \\my code
}

class B (N : Int) {
   val inst1 = new A
   val inst2 = new A


   val instN = new A
   //my code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would imply that the class would have a dynamic number of member, which is not possible.

However, there are simpler ways to express multiple elements. And that is using a collection.
In this case, I believe the best would be something with fast access by index, so I would use **ArraySeq**.

```
final class B(n: Int) {
  val instances: ArraySeq[A] = ArraySeq.tabulate(n)(_ => new A)
}
```

You may hide the collections as a private member and instead provide an access by an `apply` method.

*PS: If you are on `2.12` or a previous release, **ArraySeq** doesn't exists, you may use **Vector** instead like: `(0 to n). map(_ => new A).toVector`*